# Saving image data of the fax job

Tags: c++, unmanaged, native, fax

I'm using WinFax.dll to send and recieve faxes in my application and it works rather well for now. The problem is that I want to Save the image information in a FaxJob but the output is not any recognizable format.

I have tried with Tiff, Gif, Bmp, Png and Jpg but it is not working so I thought maybe there is a problem in how I do it. Here's the source code I have used to fetch the image:

```
public class FaxJob
{
   public Image GetImage()
   {
      uint width;
      uint height;
      uint size;
      byte[] data;
      IntPtr buffer;

      if (NativeMethods.FaxGetPageData(this.Server.faxHandle, this.id, out buffer, out size, out width, out height) == false)
         throw FaxTools.CreateFaxException(string.Empty);

      data = new byte[size];

      Marshal.Copy(buffer, data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(size));

      var ms = new MemoryStream();
      ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

      var img = Image.FromStream(ms);

      return img;
   }
}

internal class NativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("WinFax.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "FaxGetPageData")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool FaxGetPageData(IntPtr FaxHandle, uint JobId, out IntPtr Buffer, out uint BufferSize, out uint ImageWidth, out uint ImageHeight);
}
```

It seems to be working well as the image Width and Height are returned and the byte[] contains the image data.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble finding doc for WinFax.dll - so the first thing I would suggest is to fill the buffer with 0's before calling Marshal.Copy - then you will know for sure if the buffer is being filled. If it is being filled, then, you will need to look at the binary data in the file, trying to guess what format it is in - you are trying to recognize header data. If there is no header data, just the graphics, you will need to add some header info. If I could find the WinFax docs, there may be more clues there.